# Определение операционной системы

Tags: jquery, ios

Доброго времени суток!

Вот интересует есть ли возможность определить `iOS` устройство на сайте с помощью `jQuery` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Во таким образом:

```
jQuery.os =  { name: (/(win|mac|linux|sunos|solaris|iphone)/.exec(navigator.platform.toLowerCase()) || [u])[0].replace('sunos', 'solaris') };
```

Comment: а ipad?

и как этим пользоваться? я просто только вникаю в js, как вывести в алерт jQuery.os

Comment: А господин @IamS любит оставлять недосказанность ))

    alert(jQuery.os.name);

Comment: А чтоб вывести, делаем так: 

alert(jQuery.os.name);

А чтоб проверить на ipad, можете добавить его: 

(/(win|mac|linux|sunos|solaris|iphone|ipad)/

Comment: @Deonis, упс))

Comment: мега круто! спасибо за пояснения!
т.е. я могу добавить туда android и тд?

Comment: @Dimastik86, пробуйте)

Comment: андройд определяет как linux ((

Comment: `navigator.platform` андроида покажите - тогда для андроида можно прописать "исключение".